# Xtrareport Databinding format string , "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" devexpress 12.2.7

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I want to display thousand separator in Xtrareport, this code is work perfectly in DevXpress ver 14, but in ver 12.2.7, it's make an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Kho3.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

My code:

```
private void xxSL_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
            {
               xxSL.DataBindings["Text"].FormatString = "{0:N0}";
            }
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Is xxSL null? Or xxSL.DataBindings? Or xxSL.DataBindings["Text"]? If the exception happens in those lines of code i don't think there is another possibility rather than one of them is simply null.

Comment: Yes I debugged, xxSL.DataBindings["Text"] is NULL, xxSL and xxSL.DataBindings is NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress 12.2.x XRLable just don't have the DataBindings["Text"]. So I can't use it, for anyone get into this problem like me